# How to properly set server.tomcat.threads.max

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Our app is running with default 200 threads, but that seems not to be enough at peak times.
We want to increase it, but not sure by how much.

What things should be considered before setting `server.tomcat.threads.max`?

What could happen if the value is set too high?

Comment: Memory could be exhausted.  Each thread is a heavyweight thing that requires 1MB of memory.  Other factors come into play: pre-fetch size, etc.  Being careful about what those threads are doing should be your biggest concern.  Non-blocking IO and lightweight Loom threads doing the work, like Betty, might be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are hitting some other limitation (memory, cpu, database latency) and that increasing the number of threads will not solve your problem, the amount of threads is very rarely the first problem you encounter.

If you are hitting memory bounds, increasing the amount of threads will increase memory usage, further increasing your problem.

If you are hitting CPU bounds, increasing the amount of threads will also further increase your problem.

If you are hitting IO bounds, and still have CPU and memory available, you might see improvements *if* there is no contention on IO already.

You need to setup monitoring and collect statistics about your running application. This article glances over useful metrics to collect: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/tomcat-architecture-and-performance/.

To answer your question though, since you tagged your question as spring, the doc has the information you need:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.threads.max

```
server.tomcat.threads.max=250
```

Comment: Yeah, i saw that documentation, but it doesn't answer my questions, that's why i was forced to ask it here.

Comment: As I said, you are most likely hitting some other limitation. Did you profile your application? What's the memory usage, cpu usage, gc pressure, database latency? These are the questions you need to answer before even starting to tweak knobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the max-threads or threads.max properties simply does not work.

I have this in my application.properties:

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=250
server.tomcat.threads.max=250
```

But querying meterRegistry.get("tomcat.threads.config.max") always returns 200.

Check if the configuration really changes something, e.g. via JMX.

Comment: Strangely,  server.tomcat.max-connections=250 is working fine.